# Configure LocalSearch UnionMove via JavaAPI

Tags: optaplanner

Various aspects of OptaPlanner configuration can be specified in the XML config then overridden via JavaAPI. For example you can set a default TerminationConfig in your XML then at runtime switch it for a user specified value.

The docs seem to indicate that it should be possible, but I haven't found any examples. The context is that I'm hoping to dynamically alter the UnionMove section of the config and omit Swap moves if the instance to be solved doesn't have at least 2 planning entities. Currently this results in lots of Bailing from infinite logging when users are experimenting with small problems.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#solverConfigurationByJavaAPI :

```
private SolverConfig template;

public void init() {
    template = SolverConfig.createFromXmlResource(
            "org/optaplanner/examples/nqueens/solver/nqueensSolverConfig.xml");
    template.setTerminationConfig(new TerminationConfig());
}

// Called concurrently from different threads
public void userRequest(..., long userInput) {
    SolverConfig solverConfig = new SolverConfig(template); // Copy it
    solverConfig.getTerminationConfig().setMinutesSpentLimit(userInput);
    SolverFactory<NQueens> solverFactory = SolverFactory.create(solverConfig);
    Solver<NQueens> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();
    ...
}
```

In your case, you would need to modify the Phase List of the SolverConfig (see [the SolverConfig Javadocs](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-javadoc/org/optaplanner/core/config/solver/SolverConfig.html#getPhaseConfigList()) ); the move selectors can be gotten and set via [LocalSearchPhaseConfig](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-javadoc/org/optaplanner/core/config/localsearch/LocalSearchPhaseConfig.html#getMoveSelectorConfig()) and [ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-javadoc/org/optaplanner/core/config/constructionheuristic/ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig.html#getMoveSelectorConfigList()) (you need to use instanceof when iterating phase list to determine which one to cast to).

The bailing from infinite logging sound like a bug.